# Attempting to open 2 separate directories and loop through the files to gather data to amend to a main document VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping someone could help me with my code. I am pretty sure I am close to solving the issue but I just can't figure out why certain things are happening when the code runs.
My goal:

- Open up a directory that contains a main document
- Open that document and grab the last row position
- Open the Workbooks in the second directory containing multiple files with multiple sheets in each workbook.
- Open each Workbook in the client(Second) directory and check if cell A33 on each worksheet contains info.
- Grab the last row of the client file for the copy range
- Copy the data starting at A33 to U(Lastrow) and paste it to the blank row in the main document
- Update the new last row position in the main document
- Close the document and proceed to the next sheet, if there is no sheet the proceed to the next workbook and go through that workbooks sheets and repeat.

To begin - all of the code runs fine up until the second directory Do While Loop.

The first issue I am having is that my code to assign the value of the last row to a variable is returning an incorrect number.

```
'Get the last row of the client worksheet currently opened
clientLR = wsClient.Cells(wsClient.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Returns incorrect last row number (7)**
```

The second issue is that my do while function loops before the for each function can get the next file.

```
'Loop again to the next file in client directory to be opened
Loop 'Can't call next file without looping to do while statement again which opens same document**

'Call the next file in the client directory to be opened
Next file
```

Here is the full code view.

```
    Sub sourceFile2()
Call loopThroughFiles("Z:\Filepath\")
End Sub

Sub loopThroughFiles(ByVal path As String)
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim folder As Object
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)
Dim file As Object

Dim wsOverall As Worksheet
Dim wbOverall As Workbook
Dim overallLR As Long
Dim overallFilepath As String
Dim overallFile As String

Dim wbClient As Workbook
Dim clientLR As Long
Dim wsClient As Worksheet
Dim cellValue As String

'Suppress alerts for clipboard prompt bypass + screen updating
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'declare overall file path and file type
overallFilepath = "Z:\Filepath\"
overallFile = Dir(overallFilepath)

'loop through overall file directory
Do While overallFile <> ""

'Open file in overall directory
Set wbOverall = Workbooks.Open(overallFilepath & overallFile)
Set wsOverall = wbOverall.Sheets("Overall")

'Find First Blank Row in overall document
overallLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'Debug.Print overallFile
overallFile = Dir()

'Loop until no files left in directory
Loop

'For each file in the client folder
For Each file In folder.Files

'Loop through the files in client directory until no file is left
Do While file.Name <> ""
DoEvents

'Declare and open the workbook for each file in directory
Set wbClient = Application.Workbooks.Open(path & file.Name)

'For each worksheet in the Client workbook
For Each wsClient In wbClient.Worksheets

'Grab the value of Cell A33 in client workbook to compare
cellValue = Range("A33").Value

'Compare the value of cell A33 in client workbook to make sure it contains data
If cellValue <> "" Then
'Get the last row of the client worksheet currently opened
clientLR = wsClient.Cells(wsClient.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Returns incorrect last row number (7)**

'Copy the range all the way to the last row in client worksheet and paste it to the overall documents first blank row
wsClient.Range("A33:U" & clientLR).Copy
wsOverall.Range("A" & overallLR).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'Update new overall documents last row position
overallLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

End If
'Close the current opened workbook
wbClient.Close

'Call the next worksheet in the client file to be copied to the overall document again
Next wsClient

'Loop again to the next file in client directory to be opened
Loop 'Can't call next file without looping to do while statement again which opens same document**

'Call the next file in the client directory to be opened
Next file

'remainder code

'Turn alerts back on
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your loops are separated when they shouldnt be, you loop through all the files in "overallpath" and assign overallLR and you override it every time without doing anything to it, then you end that loop and you are left with the overalLR for the last file opened and you are using this one on every file that you open after. You need to Not end the loop and add the second look within this first one. For the second loop error, instead of a while File.Name <> "" just use a regular IF file.Name <> "" and it will not Re Loop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out (untested, but should be close)

```vb
Sub sourceFile2()
    Call loopThroughFiles("Z:\Filepath\")
End Sub

Sub loopThroughFiles(ByVal path As String)

    Const OVERALL_PATH As String = "Z:\Filepath\"
    
    Dim folder As Object, file
    Dim wsOverall As Worksheet, wbOverall As Workbook
    Dim overallLR As Long, overallFilepath As String
    Dim overallFile As String, wbClient As Workbook, xlFiles As Collection
    Dim clientLR As Long, wsClient As Worksheet, cellValue As String
    
    overallFile = Dir(OVERALL_PATH & "*.xls*", vbNormal) 'find the "overall" Excel file
    If Len(overallFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No overall file found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set xlFiles = AllFiles(path, "*.xls*") 'collect all Excel files in `path`
    If xlFiles.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files to process", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wbOverall = Workbooks.Open(OVERALL_PATH & overallFile)
    Set wsOverall = wbOverall.Sheets("Overall")
    overallLR = SheetLastRow(wsOverall) + 1 'next empty row
    
    For Each file In xlFiles
        Set wbClient = Application.Workbooks.Open(file)
        For Each wsClient In wbClient.Worksheets
            cellValue = wsClient.Range("A33").Value '<<< specify worksheet here!
            If Len(cellValue) > 0 Then
                clientLR = SheetLastRow(wsClient)
                If clientLR >= 33 Then
                    With wsClient.Range("A33:U" & clientLR)
                        .Copy
                        wsOverall.Range("A" & overallLR).PasteSpecial _
                              Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                        overallLR = overallLR + .Rows.Count
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next wsClient
        wbClient.Close savechanges:=False
    Next file
    
    'rest of code...
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Return all matching files in `folder` where file name matches `pattern`
Function AllFiles(ByVal folder As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim f
    Set AllFiles = New Collection
    If Right(folder, 1) <> "\" Then folder = folder & "\"
    f = Dir(folder & pattern, vbNormal)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        AllFiles.Add folder & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
End Function


'find the last used row in a sheet
Function SheetLastRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        SheetLastRow = f.Row 'otherwise 0
        Debug.Print "'" & f.Parent.Name & "' in '" & _
                     f.Parent.Parent.Name & "' = " & f.Address
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hey so the code is working pretty good. However I am having a new issue where the last row variable for clientLR is still incorrect. It is returning a value too high. As a result it is pasting large areas of blank data onto my main document. Any idea? Also I get an error at the end of the script that tells me it can't find the last file in the client directory even though it already had it open and copied some info.

Comment: It's possible there's some content on your sheets outside of where you expect - try running the edited "last row" function and check the output in the Immediate pane.

Comment: Running the code now, it shows that its overshooting each of the sheets that it is grabbing the last row from. On the bright side it is grabbing all of the correct sheets now - as shown in the panel. I am not too sure what would cause this as there is no data in these rows so it shouldn't find anything.. right?

Comment: Just a quick little thing I also noticed. It doesn't seem to be grabbing a random last row. My scroll bar is very tiny - when I scroll all the way to the bottom of the sheet it shows that row that corresponds with the clientLR. I am not sure how to go about grabbing the last row with data rather than the last row on the actual worksheet.

Comment: You'll need to inspect the cell it thinks is the last occupied and see what's there.  Impossible for me to tell without an example worksheet.  How are the sheets created?

Comment: The worksheets are sent in from the client. I am not sure how they were created. I will attempt to inspect the cell. I used =Type(A1297) and it returned a 1. Checking this shows that it is a number?

Comment: I would just look at the cell and see what's there.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not seeing anything in the range of A:AG1297. I am unsure of what could be causing this error at this point. When I press Ctrl+End it will take me to AG1297. For some reason excel believes that the last row containing information is in this row.

Comment: Can you share an example sheet which shows this?

Comment: Sure thing, here  is a link to an example of the document I have. The data has been replaced with "Data" but as you will see when you press Ctrl+End it will take you to the bottom of the document, rather than the bottom of the data. [link](https://file.io/MbExUZgmS9dp) - if you were to run the last row function I believe it will return Row 1297 instead of 374 (where the data ends)

Comment: I see a space in S1297 (which the function reports as the last cell).  You can either replace all spaces on the sheet, or since it looks like the data tables are configured as listobjects, you can get a reference to the listobject and then its `DataBodyRange`

Comment: I think it would be simpler to remove the spaces so I don't grab the blank rows - I believe if I were to reference the data tables I will run into issues since the one document has multiple sheets with various names data tables. Sorry for another question but do you know what my best route would be for removing the spaces that are causing the issue?

Comment: Try adding `wsClient.Cells.Replace " ", "", lookat:=xlWhole` before checking for the last row.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace

Comment: That did the trick, holy cow man, I appreciate all of the time and help you provided me!

Comment: So the only issue I have now is this line `Set wbClient = Application.Workbooks.Open(file.path)` - when it finishes looping through all of the files in the client folder it tries to reopen the last file and errors out.

Comment: What's the exact error message when it fails?  Does the file it's looking for actually exist?

Comment: Runtime Error '1004' Excel cannot open the file "filename" because it is corrupted verify that the file extension is correct. However the thing is that it is trying to open the last file in the folder that it already copied the data from. Like it is looping to open the same file before it checks if there are any files left in the folder.

Comment: A few changes above - different method for looping over the folder.

Comment: That rework to the way the files are handled fixed the issue. Thank you kindly!

Comment: Instead of Referencing Cell A33 for the Value is there a way for me to reference the first Cell in the Data Body Range for its Value?

Comment: Databodyrange.cells(1)

Comment: Using the code `cellValue = wsClient.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(1)` returns Runtime error 9 Subscript out of range. Using `cellValue = DataBodyRange.Cells(1)` Returns Runtime Error 424 Object Required.

Comment: If that first line errors then maybe there’s no list object on the sheet or perhaps the table is empty?  Not at a pc so can’t test

Comment: That is correct. In the first sheet I don't believe there is a listobject. I wonder how I could go about skipping to the next sheet if it doesn't find a listobject. Maybe something like `If wsClient.ListObject = "" Then Next wsClient`

Comment: Maybe check  if `wsClient.ListObjects.Count > 0`   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects

Comment: Yes that did the trick, I appreciate your help again Tim.